# python label don't updating in realtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I addressed issues with the same problem and the solution was mainly in `.set ()`.

I am a novice, I did the same and I did not succeed. Please help understand and point out the error.

I do so that in `dp1o` the value changes according to the formula xmax, but it seems that the calculation occurs only for an automatically assigned zero.

```
from math import *
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
f_top = Frame(root)
root.title('Полет ядра')
g = 9.81
dx = 0.01
v = IntVar()
an = IntVar()
t = IntVar()
vx = IntVar()

def analysis():
    v = int(entry1.get())
    an = int(entry2.get())


    t = (((2 * v * sin(an)) / g))
    vx = v * cos(an)

    xmax = vx * t * cos(an)

    dp1o.config(text=xmax)


first = LabelFrame(root, text='Данные для первого графика')
first.pack(side='left')

second = Label(first, text='Начальная скорость')
second.pack()

entry1 = Entry(first, width=10, textvariable=v)
entry1.pack()

third = Label(first, text='Угол выстрела')
third.pack()

entry2 = Entry(first, width=10, textvariable=an)
entry2.pack()


first = LabelFrame(root, text='Расчет')
first.pack(side='right')
dp1 = Label(first, text='Дальность полета 1 тела')
dp1.pack()
dp1o = Label(first, text='')
dp1o.pack()


button = Button(root, text="Сгенерировать", command=analysis())
button.pack(side='left')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you passed `()` after `analysis`. When dealing with command there is no need to put () after the function you are calling.

Here is a working version of your code.

```
from math import *
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
f_top = Frame(root)
root.title('Полет ядра')
g = 9.81
dx = 0.01
v = IntVar()
an = IntVar()
t = IntVar()
vx = IntVar()

def analysis():
    v = int(entry1.get())
    an = int(entry2.get())


    t = (((2 * v * sin(an)) / g))
    vx = v * cos(an)

    xmax = vx * t * cos(an)

    dp1o.config(text=xmax)


first = LabelFrame(root, text='Данные для первого графика')
first.pack(side='left')

second = Label(first, text='Начальная скорость')
second.pack()

entry1 = Entry(first, width=10, textvariable=v)
entry1.pack()

third = Label(first, text='Угол выстрела')
third.pack()

entry2 = Entry(first, width=10, textvariable=an)
entry2.pack()


first = LabelFrame(root, text='Расчет')
first.pack(side='right')
dp1 = Label(first, text='Дальность полета 1 тела')
dp1.pack()
dp1o = Label(first, text='')
dp1o.pack()


button = Button(root, text="Сгенерировать", command=analysis)
button.pack(side='left')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: True, it works!